# how to bind extra parameter on kendo multi select to pass onChange event

Tags: kendo-ui, onchange, multi-select

hi i am totaly new in kendo
i am try kendo MultiSelect WIDGETS
here is [**Demo**](http://demos.kendoui.com/web/multiselect/events.html)
in this demo

```
  $("#select").kendoMultiSelect({
                    dataTextField: "text",
                    dataValueField: "value",
                    dataSource: data,
                    dataBound: onDataBound,
                     change: onChange,
})
```

when change fire i want to pass one parameter this contain one one variable `MyVarText`.
how can i pass this on change event.
thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Where does this one variable comes from ?

1) if the var is from outside the multiselect just access it as shown bellow, no need to pass it

```
 $("#select").kendoMultiSelect({
                        dataTextField: "text",
                        dataValueField: "value",
                        dataSource: data,
                        dataBound: onDataBound,
                        change: function(e) {
                            MyVarText 
                          },
    })
```

2) if var is related to the multiselect, eg in the datasource, try to get it from the "e" or access the instance of the control

```
  var myMultiSel =  $("#select").kendoMultiSelect({
                            dataTextField: "text",
                            dataValueField: "value",
                            dataSource: data,
                            dataBound: onDataBound,
                            change: onChange
        }).data("kendoMultiSelect");

 function onChange(e) {
   var x =  myMultiSel.datasource. ...   
   var y = e. ..  
 }
```